# How to implement async and sync task on javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a constructor function in javascript, which name is `Man()`, it has an async method, which name is `sleep(ms)`, it will sleep `ms` seconds. It also has some sync methods, like `eat()`.

I want to implement the target like:

1. chain calling
2. the async method and sync calls as the correct order

For example:

```
new Man('Tom').sleep(3).eat('dinner')
// output: 'Hello, I am Tom'
// After 3 seconds
// output: 'Eat Dinner'
```

I have tried this:

```
function Man(name) {
  console.log(`Hello, I am ${name}`)
  return this
}
Man.prototype.sleep = function(ms) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return this
  }, ms)
}
Man.prototype.eat = function() {
  console.log('Eat Dinner')
  return this
}
```

but it didnot work as expect, it caught an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eat' of undefined`.

Comment: Print the first string to the output, return an object that has a function on it called `sleep`.  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: sleep() is an async task, eat() is a sync task, the question is, how to make async task & sync execute like a chain? for example:
```
Man('Tom').sleep(3).eat('dinner').sleep(2).jump().sleep(4).run()
```
It should have a common implemention. @David

Comment: I have edit my question @David

Comment: i am late to the party. but here you [go](https://jsfiddle.net/a10qufkh/)

Comment: Thanks, @Kharel, your solution is working on `new Man('Tom').sleep(3).eat('dinner')`, but cought error on the code as follow: `new Man('Tom').sleep(3).eat('dinner').sleep(2).jump()`.

Comment: haha, i just gave you a proof of concept that it can be done. its up to you how you use it or modify it as per your need. go wild and good luck. ;)

Comment: well, thanks at all,. @Kharel

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had work out an implementation, but not perfect.

```
function Man(name) {
  console.log(`Hello, I am ${name}`)
  this.jobs = []
  this.ms = 0
}
Man.prototype.sleep = function(ms) {
  this.ms += ms
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.next()
  }, this.ms * 1000)
  return this
}
Man.prototype.eat = function(food) {
  this.jobs.push(function() {
    console.log(`Eat ${food}`)
  })
  return this
}
Man.prototype.jump = function() {
  this.jobs.push(function() {
    console.log('Jumping...')
  })
  return this
}
Man.prototype.next = function() {
  const job = this.jobs.shift()
  if (typeof job === 'function') job.call(this)
}

new Man('Tom').sleep(3).eat('dinner').sleep(4).jump()
// output: 'Hello, I am Tom'
// After 3 seconds
// output: 'Eat dinner'
// After 4 seconds
// output: 'Jumping...'
```

Expecting a better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution:

```
const jobs = []
const next = function() {
  const job = jobs.shift()
  if (typeof job === 'function') job()
}

function Man(name) {
  console.log(`Hello, I am ${name}`)
  setTimeout(() => {
    next()
  }, 30)
  return {
    sleep: function(t) {
      jobs.push(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          next()
        }, t * 1e3)
      })
      return this
    },
    eat: function(food) {
      jobs.push(function() {
        console.log(`Eat ${food}`)
        next()
      })
      return this
    },
    jump: function() {
      jobs.push(function() {
        console.log('Jumping...')
        next()
      })
      return this
    }
  }
}
Man('Tom').sleep(3).eat('dinner').sleep(4).jump()
```